# How to execute Trigger in right way?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

**I am trying to execute trigger but facing error:**

If one record is inserting to registration table , same time I have check ,if that entry is having referal_code or not. If record having referal_code then I have to insert master_id,district_id,taluka_id and assign_to fields which are on another table(franchisee_code).

**for this case I write following trigger**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `assign_to` AFTER INSERT ON `registration` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF (SELECT master_id,district_id,taluka_id,assign_to FROM franchisee_code WHERE franchisee_code.referal_code=NEW.referal_code) THEN UPDATE registration SET NEW.master_id =franchisee_code.master_id,NEW.district_id =franchisee_code.district_id,NEW.taluka_id =franchisee_code.taluka_id,NEW.assign_to =franchisee_code.assign_to WHERE NEW.id=NEW.id; END
```

**but showing following error**

The following query has failed:

```
"CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `assign_to` AFTER INSERT ON `registration` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT master_id,district_id,taluka_id,assign_to FROM franchisee_code WHERE franchisee_code.referal_code=NEW.referal_code; UPDATE registration SET NEW.master_id =franchisee_code.master_id,NEW.district_id =franchisee_code.district_id,NEW.taluka_id =franchisee_code.taluka_id,NEW.assign_to =franchisee_code.assign_to WHERE NEW.id=NEW.id END"
```

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5

**Kindly help me to overcome this problem.**

Comment: Which Database you use ? conflict with your tag and error message

Comment: its MySQL Database.

Comment: Which mysql version is this ? could you please add complete trigger creation code ?

Comment: Please do not add trigger code in comment , edit your question

Comment: mysql version is 5.6

Comment: I think you first look at the trigger syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an end if; and you may not be setting delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. Also you cannot update the table which fired the trigger in the trigger. You can update NEW. values in a before trigger but not an after trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger should be something like below.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS assign_to ;
DELIMITER$$
CREATE TRIGGER assign_to AFTER INSERT ON registration
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  SET @masterId := 0;
  SET @districtId := 0;
  SET @talukaId := 0;
  SET @assignTo := 0;
    SELECT master_id ,district_id, taluka_id , assign_to 
    INTO @masterId, @districtId,@talukaId,@assignTo 
    FROM franchisee_code 
    WHERE franchisee_code.referal_code = NEW.referal_code;

   IF @masterId > 0 THEN
       UPDATE registration 
    SET NEW.master_id = @masterId, 
    NEW.district_id = @districtId, 
    NEW.taluka_id = @talukaId, 
    NEW.assign_to = @assignTo 
    WHERE NEW.id=NEW.id ;
   END IF;
 END$$
```

But as you are try to update the same row which you have entered, then mysql won't allow you to do this.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/MOSZHI96869)

Comment: facing error 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER//
CREATE TRIGGER assign_to AFTER INSERT ON registration
FOR EACH ROW' at line 1

Comment: @NikhilBhalerao If you are using MySQL then why your system shows **MariaDB ** related errors ?

Comment: is there any issue of php version ?

Comment: Instead of PHP try to execute this from MySQL command prompt.

Comment: not working. what will alternate option for such a case?

Comment: @NikhilBhalerao I have change the Delimiter in above answer, could you please check now.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER$$
CREATE TRIGGER assign_to AFTER INSERT ON registration
FOR EACH ROW 
' at line 1

Comment: @NikhilBhalerao where are you executing this query, console or from GUI ?